# Is it fine to use Getx for state management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am building a big/complex e-commerce app and I am currently using Getx for state management. Some people are saying it is bad because it does a lot of things and if it breaks, your whole app will break while some others say it is good and I can go with it. Suppose that I will use this package for state management only, not for routing, dialogs, snackbars, etc. will that be fine? if not, can you suggest some alternatives for state management?

Answer (score 2):

For better management performance and good architecture you can use riverpod or bloc

**Riverpod**

1. riverpod can also works with hookswidget very well than help you to make your code more reusable
2. riverpod is currently mostly used by developers
3. riverpod have many built in providers like future provider strema provider etc

**Bloc**

1. bloc also a good package it make you code more easily maintanable form
2. you can easily separate your repository and logic and views and make your code more readable and maintable
3. Bloc works best with streams and other soultuions